# What about the Scala-Performance tag - do we need it?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have seen a new tag [`scala-performance`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-performance) been retagged today. But do we really need it? All theses questions already have the tag `scala` and the tag `performance` could be added if needed. If one want the questions with `scala` and `performance` it's easy to search on `[scala] [performance]`.

I suggest that we stop using the tag [`scala-performance`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-performance). Used on 21 questions.

An example is [How well does Scala Perform Comapred to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479819/how-well-does-scala-perform-comapred-to-java) that now has the tags `[performance] [scala] [scala-performance]`

Comment: @Jonas Sorry if I misused this tag. I was compiling information on Scala performance and thought it would be nice to have a relevant series of correctly tagged questions. `[javascript-performance]`, `[wcf-performance]`, `[jquery-performance]`, `[sqlperformance]`, etc. exist too, so I thought it was a good thing to have this for Scala as well.

Comment: @Jean: But I don't see the point, we can use `[scala][performance]` for these questions because all of them already has `[scala]`. Or isn't this enough?

Comment: @Jean: Maybe it is good. But it would be good to discuss it here on Meta before doing a massively retagging.

Comment: Don’t know: I'm especially interested in Scala collections and Scala performance. Now I can subscribe to `[scala-collections]` and `[scala-performance]` without getting the whole traffic about `[scala]` and `[performance]`. But I agree that you have a point, which should actually be made for *all* compound tags all over SE, shouldn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I've missed that step — I'm not too familiar with Meta and didn't really know where to discuss such matters… I guess I know now! :-)

Comment: @Jean: I think it usually is, that's why every question has up to five tags.

Comment: @Jonas I think it's nice to talk more particularly about Scala performance (and show that it important enough to have its own tag) with the recent efforts from the Scala team with stuff like @specialized and parallel collections. But you have been here longer, I trust your judgement on this, I don't have strong opinion.

Comment: BTW I think that if you create a new tag, you should definitely spend time scanning questions that deserve it and retag them appropriately…

Comment: I've asked a question to address the more general issue of such “compound tags”: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88554/160564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a matter of filtering the scala-related posts about performance, then it should be enough a simple query like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala+performance

or the RSS feed:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/scala+performance?sort=newest

But, clearly, this applies to every language, not only scala, so if the question is: *"Is **Scala-Performance tag** particularly bad?"*, I would say no, it isn't. But, if the question is *"Are all the **LANGUAGE-Performance tags** required at all?"*, I'm inclined to answer no, they're not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think that scala-performance may indeed be a valid tag. Especially for people watching the tags as given the wide ranging number of questions that performance will give.

Obviously there are language specific performance and generic performance to be taken into account.

Someone who subscribes to scala performance probably isn't intrested in javascript performance.